# .NET method to parse String with Long type qualifier

Tags: .net, parsing, int64

I get a string from a 3rd party SW with a long type qualifier, e.g. "1L".
I want to parse this to an Int64, but Int64.TryParse does not recognize this as an Int64.
Is there a .NET method that does this safely? I want to avoid parsing myself...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `String.Replace("L","")` ?

Comment: You replace the `L` (or `l`) if it's 1) Not the first non-whitespace character; and 2) it is the last character or is followed immediately by a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, you can do this:

```
string sNum = "1L";
int pos = sNum.IndexOf('L');
if (pos == sNum.Length-1)
{
    sNum = sNum.Substring(0, sNum.Length-1);
}
long num = int64.Parse(sNum);
```

Comment: So I don't really understand this conversion, but if the `L` were in the first position, would `Int64.Parse` work?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: According to the documentation, `Int64.Parse` wants `[whitespace][sign]digits[whitespace]`. There is no allowance for a leading or trailing type specifier.

Comment: Now I understand, and so that trailing type specifier (e.g. `L`) isn't really standard and rather just an artifact of where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

From browsing around, the best I can recommend is using a regular expression to either extract 
or remove the non numeric characters, and then to parse with the framework (Convert, Parse or TryParse etc).

I poached this from one of the questions below, hope it works:

```
var originalString = "9L";
var result = Convert.ToInt64(Regex.Replace(originalString, "[^0-9]", String.Empty));
```

See these questions for some examples (and some, err, ...interesting alternative approaches):

- [Parse a number from a string with non-digits in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204673/parse-number-from-string-value-in-c-sharp)
- [String parsing, extracting numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734937/string-parsing-extracting-numbers-and-letters)

Comment: Thanks, I hoped I could avoid string manipulation, but this will work.

Comment: So that will make "93foobar265" into "93265"? Fun.

Comment: Yep Jim, not the cleanest but the best I could find. The regex could be changed easily enough to only replace L or l (as per your comment) but the OP wasn't really clear about what the constraints or possible positions of the alpha characters could be

Comment: Incidentally, Jim, I think your answer would handle 93foobar265 by throwing a NumberFormatException? With a modified regex I think this answer would give the same behavior. That would be preferable, if there is some way the incoming string might look something other than alpha + L ... Like OP says would be great if there was a framework method :)